# Is this design introducing Circular Dependency?

Tags: java, class, oop, factory, enumeration

Supposed I have two types of customers - Regular and VIP. I would like to give discounts to them based on CustomerType and their attributes. I have following design in my mind:

```
class Customer {

  CustomerType customerType; 
  // Has some attributes
}

Enum CustomerType {

  REGULAR("Regular", new RegularDiscountCalculatorFactory()),
  VIP("VIP", new VIPDiscountCalculatorFactory());

  String value;
  DiscountCalculatorFactory discountCalculatorFactory;

  //Constructor and Getters
}

abstract class DiscountCalculatorFactory {
  public abstract DiscountCalculator getDiscountCalculator(Customer customer);
}

class RegularDiscountCalculatorFactory extends DiscountCalculatorFactory {
  public DiscountCalculator getDiscountCalculator(Customer customer) {
    return new RegularDiscountCalculator(customer);
  }
}

class VIPDiscountCalculatorFactory extends DiscountCalculatorFactory {
  public DiscountCalculator getDiscountCalculator(Customer customer) {
    return new VIPDiscountCalculator(customer);
  }
}

abstract class DiscountCalculator {

  Customer customer;
  public DiscountCalculator(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
  }

  public int calculateDiscount() {
    //Common Implementation of calculating discount
  }
}

class RegularDiscountCalculator extends DiscountCalculator {
  public RegularDiscountCalculator(Customer customer) {
    super(customer);
  }
}

class VIPDiscountCalculator extends DiscountCalculator {
  public RegularDiscountCalculator(Customer customer) {
    super(customer);
  }

  @Override
  public int calculateDiscount() {
    //Some different implementation
    return super.calculateDiscount();
  }
}

class Main {
  Customer customer = new Customer("VIP", .../* other attributes */ );
  DiscountCalculatorFactory discountCalculatorFactory = customer.getCustomerType().getDiscountCalculatorFactory()
  DiscountCalculator discountCalculator = discountCalculatorFactory.getDiscountCalculator(customer);
  int discount = discountCalculator.calculateDiscount();
  System.out.println("Discount: " + discount);
}
```

I know discount calculator should not contain Customer but please let it slide as this is just an analogy and it makes perfect sense in actual case. I would like to understand here whether I am introducing circular dependency or not?

Comment: I do not see a circular dependency on object level. I see, however, a circular dependency on class-level and the choice to couple the `CustomerType` with the `DiscountCalculator(Factory)`. The circular dependency on class-level couples the `Customer` hard to the `DiscountCalculator`. I also do not understand why a `DiscountCalculator` needs to have a state instead of just expecting a `Customer` as argument for its `calculateDiscount(...)`-method.

Answer (score 0):

You are right - it is a circular dependency.

Despite you don't have this dependency at the object level (your object instances don't have links one to each other) you have general design circular dependency.
Java Compilers allow you to compile this code if it is within a single module, and will throw an compile-time error if you split it into several modules - circular dependencies are forbidden across modules.
Even if you could compile this code - such circular dependencies are a sign of poor hard coupled design which will be hard to maintain and expand.

In this particular situation, the main problem is that your `Customer` is aware of the type of the `DiscountCalcualtor` it should use, as well as the `DiscountCalculator` implementation depends on the `Customer`. It means that if you introduce a new `CustomerType` value, you should implement a new `DiscountCalculator` and tight this Calculator to a particular `Customer` inside `enum CustomerType`. If you redesign your Calculators and for example reduce implementations or add some specific ones, you should "inform" `Customer` by updating your `enum CustomerType`.

One change in your design lead to multiple changes in different parts of the system.

There are several ways to get rid of circular dependencies and make application design clean. Here are some ideas that you can apply to this situation:

1. Get rid of the `enum CustomerType` or at least remove all "factory-related logic" from the enum. `Customer` shouldn't be aware of `DiscountCalculator` and the structure of your application (it knows that your use a factory pattern to create `DiscountCalculator`). Add the factory method to `DiscountCalculator`, and make this class responsible for providing you with the right factory.
   For example:

```
class DiscountCalculatorFactory {

  private DiscountCalculatorFactory() {}

  public static DiscountCalculator getDiscountCalculator(Customer customer) {
    CustomerType type = customer.getCustomerType();
    return switch (type) {
      case VIP -> new VIPDiscountCalculator(customer);
      case REGULAR -> new RegularDiscountCalculator(customer);
      default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(type.toString());
    };
  }
}
```

You can implement it in different ways, but the general idea - the `Customer` shouldn't be aware of the `DiscountCalculator` as well as of application structure and other plumbing code.

2. Do not recommend changing the implementation of `DiscountCalculator` and make it stateless by using `Customer` as an argument to your `public int calculateDiscount()`. It seems the easiest way, but you still have all the problems we discussed above, and circular dependency at the class level is in place - but they are more difficult to spot now. Also if we make the class stateless we lose some advantages of the OOP paradigm - encapsulation of both *data* and *methods* of processing.